# JSON + Polish characters

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8

I'm using JSON to send array from PHP to Javascript. The array is getting data form the database. I've searched multiple topics on problem with JSON and foreign characters and everybody says that to solve the problem you have to set encoding to utf-8. I have done it I think but it just not help me. So i run the test to see what is the problem. To make it easy and simple i try to pass the string with polish characters to json_encode() function. So i have created index.php file. In my text editor i choose option Encode in UTF-8 without BOM and i started to code:

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 $data = "polish characters: ążśęłóćźć";
 $jsonData = json_encode($data);
 echo mb_detect_encoding($data) . "<br />;
 echo $jsonData;
?>
```

The result is:

```
UTF-8
"polish characters : \u0105\u017c\u015b\u0119\u0142\u00f3\u0107\u017a\u0107"
```

I still can't output polish characters. I don't know what is wrong? Please Help :)

Comment: Where do you see this output? It doesn't really make sense to echo JSON data straight into an HTML page and expect it to be renderer in a meaningful way. It could be part of a JavaScript script there, but you'd have to process it somehow too.

Comment: You have a typo in your php.

Comment: Why are you setting the header to text/html when your outputting JSON? If you don't JSON encode the string (or even encode it and then decode it) then the polish characters will be displayed. Or if your wanting to output the data as JSON then the UTF-8 encoding (\u0105) is preserved and can be translated by whatever code is reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
echo json_decode(json_encode($data));
```

You should see that the Polish characters are displayed just fine.

Applications should not display JSON directly to the end user, but should first parse it to a more human friendly format. If you follow that rule, `json_encode` should not give you any issues, as you will always decode and parse it into any format that is appropriate.

Comment: Omg what a embaressment:) You all have right there was no problem to begin with. I created it myself. I just needed a method to pass the multidimensional array from php to javascript and i saw this method with JSON. And when i encode it from couriosity i echoed encoded array from PHP because i was courious. And when i saw that there was no polish characters then all it gets started. I wasted basically couple hours trying to put back polish characters to encoded array:) and i was so blinded that i didnt try to output the decoded array from javascript.Anyway thanks for Helping me out so quickly